# How to add or remove classes based on browser height resize using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window-resize

I would like to know if there's a way to add or remove classes based on the browser's height. Right now, I am comparing a div against the browser height and adding a class to it if the browser's height is higher than the div height by doing this:

```
if (($(window).height()) > $(".sidebar").height()) {
    $("#widget-area").addClass("fixed");
} else {

}
```

This works since the class is being added when the condition is met. The problem is that if the user resizes the browser's height, the class that was added will keep added even if the condition is not met anymore.

Is there a way to listen to the browser's height and add or remove this class no matter if the browser is resized later on?

**EDIT:**

I know a lot of you might suggest doing this by media queries but I need this to be done using jQuery.

I have added the window on resize function as suggested. The problem is that the script will only run if the browser is resized. I need it to run as soon as the document is ready and if the browser is resized as well. Here is my code:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if (($(window).height()) > $(".sidebar").height()) {
        $("#widget-area").addClass("fixed");
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: Don't use JS for this - use a CSS [Media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: You should run the code when window resize.

Comment: I always recommend css instead of js for this stuff but if you still want to do it like that you need to add your code inside of `$( window ).resize(function() {//code here/)}`

Comment: Thanks @sTx . I have added the windows resize but now the script will only run if the browser is resized. I would it to run when the document is loaded and if the browser is resized.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. However, for this project I need to approach this via jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) is a good way to do this work. But if you want to use jQuery, you should run the code when window resize.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).height() > $(".sidebar").height())
    $("#widget-area").addClass("fixed");
  else
    $("#widget-area").removeClass("fixed");
});
```

Also if you want to run code when page load, use `.on()` and add two event handler to it.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
  if ($(window).height() > $(".sidebar").height())
    $("#widget-area").addClass("fixed");
  else
    $("#widget-area").removeClass("fixed");
});
```

See code result in [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7p81gjuk/)

Comment: Hi @Mohammad, I added both your second code and it loads once the page is loaded but it wont remove the class if the browser is resized.

Comment: @Johann If height of window resized less than 300px, color of text maked black. Test the provided demo

Comment: That's true, your demo works perfect and that's the correct answer. You can post it and I will mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution via javascript:**

If `.sidebar` has a dynamic height, here is one approach using javascript:

```
function updateWidgetAreaClassList() {
    var widgetArea = document.getElementById('widget-area');
    var sideBar = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar')[0];

    if (window.innerHeight > sideBar.offsetHeight) {
        widgetArea.classList.add('fixed');
    }

    else {
        widgetArea.classList.remove('fixed');
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', updateWidgetAreaClassList, false);
```

---

**Solution via CSS `@media` query:**

If `.sidebar` has a fixed height of `400px` (for example), the CSS `@media` query would be the following:

```
@media screen and (min-height: 401px ) {

#widget-area { [... STYLES HERE...] }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function for manipulating your dom in your case add and remove classes. And call that funciton in document.ready function and window.resize function. See below a working example

http://codepen.io/harishgadiya/pen/VpNXmB

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**css**

```
#wrapper{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background:#999
}
.red{
  background:red !important;

}
```

**JS**

```
function resize(){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var wrapperHeight = $('#wrapper').height();
  console.log(windowHeight , wrapperHeight)
  if(windowHeight > wrapperHeight) $('#wrapper').addClass("red");
  else $('#wrapper').removeClass("red");
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  resize()
});

$(window).resize(resize)
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I've seen in an answer above `$(window).on('load resize', function(){..` which should do the job you can also do something like this:

```js
var handleResize = function(){
  if (($(window).height()) > $(".sidebar").height()) {
        $("#widget-area").addClass("fixed");
  } else {
  //some other thing    
  } 
}
  $(document).ready(function(){
    handleResize();
  })
  $(window).on('resize', function(){
    handleResize();
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Go for media query
@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {

.fixed :100px;



}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this is not a viable solution since all the content's height is variable. There are no fixed values.